# How to assertValue input array

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Using selenium ide, how do you assert a value from an input array index?

For example, I have the following html:

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" name="itemid[]" value="1"></input></td>
<td><input type="text" name="itemcode[]" value="code1"></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" name="itemid[]" value="2"></input></td>
<td><input type="text" name="itemcode[]" value="code2"></input></td>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I assert the value of the second hidden input value with the name 'itemid[]'?

I have been trying things such as with out success:

(//input[@name='itemid[]'])[2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try explicitly specifying xpath:

```
<tr>
    <td>verifyElementPresent</td>
    <td>xpath=(//input[@name='itemcode[]'])[2]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```